# Agora cloud recording separating audio and video files in azure, but I need one file with both audio and video

Tags: javascript, node.js, agora.io, video-recording, agora-web-sdk-ng

```
const request = {
        uid: '999',
        cname: `${channelName}`,
        clientRequest: {
        token: EventService.getRecordingToken(channelName),//tocken of 999
        recordingConfig: {
             maxIdleTime: 120,
             streamTypes: 2,
             channelType: 0,
             videoStreamType: 0,
             subscribeVideoUids: [idsToUse.uId + ""],
             subscribeAudioUids: [idsToUse.uId + ""],
             subscribeUidGroup: 0
        },
        recordingFileConfig: {
             avFileType: ["hls"]
        },
        storageConfig: {
             accessKey: process.env.AZURE_ACCESS_KEY,
             region: 3,//The region parameter has no effect, whether or not it is set.(Ref:https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=RESTful)
             bucket: `${process.env.AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME}`,
             secretKey: process.env.AZURE_SECRET_KEY,
             vendor: 5
       }
     }
  };
```

This is my start recording configurations for individual recording for a livestream for my app.
By this I got 2 files one is .audio.m3u8 and 2nd is .video.m3u8 but my requirement is only one file with both audio and video in it. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use Cloud Composite Recording API Transcoding

https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_composite_mode?platform=RESTful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).